# how to place button at mailcomposerviewcontroller tabbar to get contacts

Tags: iphone

i need to send email in my application.for that i need to add one contacts button,to get contacts from the address book.

so that i need to place one button at tab bar of mailcomposerviewcontroller.

how can i can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that this isn't possible.

However the MFMailViewController does allow for the search of contacts in the normal way that it is done in Mail.app.

You could also have a view prior to presenting to the mail controller for selecting contacts and then add the contacts that were chosen before presenting the MFMailViewController.